# How do I multiply multiple rows with each other? (AMATEUR)

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

```
SELECT 
    tbl_route.Frequency,
    tbl_operatorrouterelation.ProportionOfRoute
FROM
    tbl_operatorrouterelation
        INNER JOIN
    tbl_route ON tbl_operatorrouterelation.RouteID = tbl_route.RouteID
WHERE
    tbl_route.routeID IN (SELECT 
            to3.RouteID
        FROM
            tbl_operatorrouterelation to3
        WHERE
            to3.operatorID = (SELECT 
                    to2.operatorid
                FROM
                    tbl_operatordesc to2
                WHERE
                    to2.Name = 'OK Travel'))
        AND tbl_operatorrouterelation.operatorID = (SELECT 
            to2.operatorid
        FROM
            tbl_operatordesc to2
        WHERE
            to2.Name = 'OK Travel')
```

This code returns this:
[image: The Code returns this]

How can I multiply the values on each row together then get the sum of all those?

This is what I need to do:

```
(4*25)+(4*100)+(4*50)
```

using the values from the table.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what  you mean. maybe you could make a [mre] to show what the rewsult shpuld be from the presented data

Comment: Yep. It really is that simple

Answer (score 1):

Multiply  the columns and make a SUM of the multiplication

```
SELECT 
    SUM(tbl_route.Frequency * tbl_operatorrouterelation.ProportionOfRoute)
FROM
    tbl_operatorrouterelation
        INNER JOIN
    tbl_route ON tbl_operatorrouterelation.RouteID = tbl_route.RouteID
WHERE
    tbl_route.routeID IN (SELECT 
            to3.RouteID
        FROM
            tbl_operatorrouterelation to3
        WHERE
            to3.operatorID = (SELECT 
                    to2.operatorid
                FROM
                    tbl_operatordesc to2
                WHERE
                    to2.Name = 'OK Travel'))
        AND tbl_operatorrouterelation.operatorID = (SELECT 
            to2.operatorid
        FROM
            tbl_operatordesc to2
        WHERE
            to2.Name = 'OK Travel')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUM(tbl_route.Frequency * tbl_operatorrouterelation.ProportionOfRoute) from ....
```

Comment: please add always some text ro your answer.